# How to calculate the mean and the std of cifar10 data

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

Pytorch is using the following values as the mean and std for the cifar10 data:
transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

I need to understand the concept behind calculating it because this data is 3 channel image and I do not understand what is summed and divided over what and so on.
Also if someone can share a code for calculating the mean and the std, would be so thankful.

Answer (score 9):

The 0.5 values are just approximates for ***cifar10*** mean and std values over the three channels (r,g,b). The precise values for cifar10 train set are

- mean: `0.49139968, 0.48215827 ,0.44653124`
- std: `0.24703233 0.24348505 0.26158768`

You may calculate these using the following script:

```
import torch
import numpy
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torchvision import transforms

cifar_trainset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

imgs = [item[0] for item in cifar_trainset] # item[0] and item[1] are image and its label
imgs = torch.stack(imgs, dim=0).numpy()

# calculate mean over each channel (r,g,b)
mean_r = imgs[:,0,:,:].mean()
mean_g = imgs[:,1,:,:].mean()
mean_b = imgs[:,2,:,:].mean()
print(mean_r,mean_g,mean_b)

# calculate std over each channel (r,g,b)
std_r = imgs[:,0,:,:].std()
std_g = imgs[:,1,:,:].std()
std_b = imgs[:,2,:,:].std()
print(std_r,std_g,std_b)
```

Also, you may find the same mean and std values [here](https://github.com/tomgoldstein/loss-landscape/blob/64ef4d57f8dabe79b57a637819c44e48eda98f33/cifar10/dataloader.py#L15) and [here](https://gist.github.com/weiaicunzai/e623931921efefd4c331622c344d8151#gistcomment-2851662)

Answer (score 6):

Alternative way

```
from  torchvision import datasets

cifar_trainset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True  )
data = cifar_trainset.data / 255 # data is numpy array

mean = data.mean(axis = (0,1,2)) 
std = data.std(axis = (0,1,2))
print(f"Mean : {mean}   STD: {std}") #Mean : [0.491 0.482 0.446]   STD: [0.247 0.243 0.261]
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers either relied on loading each image individually (which is incredibly slow) or assuming that the dataset saves the data as one large numpy array.

A more general and fast approach is to use a PyTorch DataLoader.

```
def get_mean_std(trainLoader):
    imgs = None
    for batch in trainLoader:
        image_batch = batch[0]
        if imgs is None:
            imgs = image_batch.cpu()
        else:
            imgs = torch.cat([imgs, image_batch.cpu()], dim=0)
    imgs = imgs.numpy()
    
    # calculate mean over each channel (r,g,b)
    mean_r = imgs[:,0,:,:].mean()
    mean_g = imgs[:,1,:,:].mean()
    mean_b = imgs[:,2,:,:].mean()
    print(mean_r,mean_g,mean_b)

    # calculate std over each channel (r,g,b)
    std_r = imgs[:,0,:,:].std()
    std_g = imgs[:,1,:,:].std()
    std_b = imgs[:,2,:,:].std()
    print(std_r,std_g,std_b)
```