# Batch size reduces accuracy of ensemble of pretrained CNNs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement basic softmax-based voting, which I take a couple of pretrained CNNs, softmax their outputs, add them together and then use argmax as final output.

So I loaded 4 different pretrained CNNs (`vgg11`, `vgg13`, `vgg16`, `vgg19`) from `"chenyaofo/pytorch-cifar-models"` that were trained on CIFAR10 -- I didn't train them.

- When I iterate over the test set with DataLoader with `batch_size=128/256`,  I get to 94% accuracy;
- When I iterate over the test set with `batch_size=1`, I get to 69% accuracy.

How could it be?

This is the code:

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

torch.cuda.empty_cache()

model_names = [
        "cifar10_vgg11_bn",
        "cifar10_vgg13_bn",
        "cifar10_vgg16_bn",
        "cifar10_vgg19_bn",
        # "cifar10_resnet56",
]

batch_size = 2

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

def load_models():
    models = []
    for model_name in model_names:
        model = torch.hub.load("chenyaofo/pytorch-cifar-models", model_name, pretrained=True)
        models.append(model)
    return models

testset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=test_transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class MyEnsemble(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, modelA, modelB, modelC, modelD):
        super(MyEnsemble, self).__init__()
        self.modelA = modelA
        self.modelB = modelB
        self.modelC = modelC
        self.modelD = modelD
        # self.modelE = modelE

    def forward(self, x):
        out1 = self.modelA(x)
        out2 = self.modelB(x)
        out3 = self.modelC(x)
        out4 = self.modelD(x)
        # out5 = self.modelE(x)

        # print(out1.shape)

        out1 = torch.softmax(out1, dim=1)
        out2 = torch.softmax(out2, dim=1)
        out3 = torch.softmax(out3, dim=1)
        out4 = torch.softmax(out4, dim=1)

        out = out1 + out2 + out3 + out4

        return out

from EnsembleModule import MyEnsemble
from data import load_models, testloader
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

models = load_models()

model = MyEnsemble(models[0], models[1], models[2], models[3])

model.to(device)

total = 0
correct = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in tqdm(testloader):
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        _, predictions = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predictions == labels).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to call `model.eval()`:

```py
# ...

model.to(device)
model.eval() # <<<<<<<<<<<<<

total = 0
correct = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in tqdm(testloader):
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)

# ...
```

As your model has BatchNorm layers, batch_size=1 is particularly degrading.

The pre-processing should also follow the one used for training. As you can see in the [repository of the author](https://colab.research.google.com/github/chenyaofo/pytorch-cifar-models/blob/master/colab/start_on_colab.ipynb) of the model, you should normalize using the following [statistics](https://github.com/chenyaofo/image-classification-codebase/blob/9eb344d237448f96c2ae50c1dfeab7608be768f7/conf/cifar10.conf#L25-L26):

```py
test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), std=(0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))
])
```

Comment: well now its 30% with batch size = 1 and model.eval()...

Comment: @JojoHalastra and how much did you get with `batch_size=128/256` and `.eval()`?

Comment: with 256 batch size and .eval() I get also 30%... this is really weird..

Comment: @JojoHalastra I updated with the statistics used by the author of the model you're using, which is slightly different than the usual ones.

Comment: @JojoHalastra BTW, the `std` values of Ivan's answer are incorrect for your model. The correct ones are defined [here](https://github.com/chenyaofo/image-classification-codebase/blob/9eb344d237448f96c2ae50c1dfeab7608be768f7/conf/cifar10.conf#L25-L26)

Comment: Agreed, for some reason chenyaofo's stats are different from the ones used by `torchvision`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using models containing batchnorm layers (indicated by the `_bn` suffix in the `torchvision`'s model name).

This in turn means the results will depend on the statistics of the current batch. These being different when using `batch_size=2` and `batch_size=128`. When evaluating you should always call the [`nn.Module.eval`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) function. This makes the layer use running statistics (those learned during training) and not the batch's statistics. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch) for more information.

Do note calling eval will recursively propagates to all child modules, so you only have to make a single call on yoru ensemble module directly:

```
model = MyEnsemble(models[0], models[1], models[2], models[3])
model.eval()
```

This being done, the batch size should have no effect on the performance of your model.

When training, you will need to turn back training mode on with [`nn.Module.train`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train).

---

You need to normalize the data based on the [dataset's statistics](https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/issues/19), you can do so in the torchvision preprocessing pipeline:

```
test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))]))
```

Comment: well now its 30% with batch size = 1 and model.eval()...

Comment: Did you normalize your test data in the preprocessing?

Comment: it worked! how did you know the normalization's values?

Comment: I found those [here](https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/issues/19) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678052/how-to-calculate-the-mean-and-the-std-of-cifar10-data). But you should use the stats used for training the model. @Berriel below linked the repo with the correct values. They're slightly different to the ones used by the models provided by `torchvision`.